# equality of support of a module and its quotient

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, krull-dimension, cohen-macaulay

Reference: Atiyah and Macdonald, *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*, page 46.

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with 1 and $M$ a $A$-module. Then we define $\mathrm{Supp}(M)$ to be the set of prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$ such that $M_{\mathfrak{p}}\neq 0$.

It is known that in every exact sequence $0\longrightarrow N \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow M/N\longrightarrow0$ of $A$-modules one have:

$\mathrm{Supp}(N) \subseteq \mathrm{Supp}(M)=\mathrm{Supp}(N)\bigcup \mathrm{Supp}(M/N)$.

> When in such an exact sequence as above, $\mathrm{Supp}(N) \subseteq \mathrm{Supp}(M/N)$ and hence $\mathrm{Supp}(M)=\mathrm{Supp}(M/N)?$

I want to prove if $\dim M=d$ and $N$ is Cohen-Macaulay of dimension $d-1$ and $M/N$ is Cohen-Macaulay of dimension $d$ then $\mathrm{Supp}(M)=\mathrm{Supp}(M/N)$.

Comment: You are trying to prove a false statement. As an example, take $A=k[x]\times k$, $M=A$ and $N=0\times k$.